# Jarvis March implemention going into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I implemented Jarvis march in javascript and then submitted it, turns out in some cases it goes into an infinite loop. I tried changing almost everything and it seems like the code keeps on going into an infinite loop just for a few test cases.

This is my current code, the last for loop is to get all the points lying on the lines made by the convex hull points.

```js
function convexHull(points, n)
        {
            // There must be at least 3 points
                if (n < 3) return;

                // Find the leftmost point
                let l = 0;
                let hull = [];
                for (let i = 1; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        if (points[i].x < points[l].x)
                            l = i;
                        else if (points[i].x == points[l].x && points[i].y < points[l].y)
                            l = i;
                    }

                // Start from leftmost point, keep moving
                // counterclockwise until reach the start point
                // again. This loop runs O(h) times where h is
                // number of points in result or output.
                let p = l, q;

                
                do
                {

                    // Add current point to result
                    hull.push(points[p]);
                    newhull.push(points[p]);
                    // Search for a point 'q' such that
                    // orientation(p, q, x) is counterclockwise
                    // for all points 'x'. The idea is to keep
                    // track of last visited most counterclock-
                    // wise point in q. If any point 'i' is more
                    // counterclock-wise than q, then update q.
                    q = (p + 1) % n;

                    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                       // If i is more counterclockwise than
                       // current q, then update q
                       if ((orientation(points[p], points[i], points[q])
                                                           == 2))
                           q = i;
                        if(p != i && orientation(points[p], points[i], points[q]) == 0 
                           && onSegment(points[p], points[q], points[i])) {
                           q = i;
                           }
                    }
                    
                    p = q;

                  }while (p != l);  // While we don't come to first point
                
                  

                for(let i = 0; i < hull.length; i++) {
                  if(i + 1 < hull.length) {
                  for (let j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                    if(orientation(hull[i], points[j], hull[i+1]) == 0) {
                      newhull.push(points[j]);
                        points.splice(j, 1);
                        j--; }
                    }  
                  }
                  else if(i + 1 == hull.length) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                      if(orientation(hull[i], points[j], hull[i+1]) == 0) {
                        newhull.push(points[j]);
                        points.splice(j, 1);
                        j--;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
```

Any help pointing out how I could improve this or get out of an infinite loop would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two things will encourage users to answer. (1) Instead of pasting your code with { }, use the icon two steps to the right. This allows you to create an executable snippet, that users can run by clicking. (2) Include an example of the test case that goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Eureka I can't show the test case as it's hidden. Very sorry

Comment: In that case, create a case yourself that fails. Otherwise you are asking other people to solve a puzzle that someone has set you.